# Build failed after ejecting from expo

Tags: react-native, expo

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > project :expo-camera
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > project :expo-camera
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

Answer (score 3):

Go to *android/build.gradle* and in *repositories* add

```
        maven {
        // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
    }
```

then in terminal `cd android` and `gradlew clean`
then go back to your project folder and try again `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup all the environment requirements?

If not you need to set up the following before building a standalone app without expo.

[React Native environment set up](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Follow the steps in above link